# Set FontFamily from a file in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, file, fonts

I'm writing a program that have two `TextBlock` with each specific `FontFamily` set. I set each font using it's `FontFamily` variable. `FontFamily` variables are being set in a method that is loaded from certain `.ttf` files. These may or may not be installed on the system.

I have failed to find a way to set `FontFamily` from a `.ttf` file, because `.ttf` files cannot  be stored by the program (font files replaces runtime).

Some of my attempts

```
String textFontName = "nameOfFont";

FontFamily textFont = new FontFamily(new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/themes/tmp/text/#" + textFontName, UriKind.Absolute), textFontName); // Not Work if font is not installed
```

**Edit:** This one:

```
textFont = new FontFamily("file:///" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/themes/tmp/text/#" + textFontName);
```

and this one is very interesting:

```
textFont = new FontFamily(new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/themes/tmp/text/text.ttf", UriKind.Absolute), "./#" + textFontName);
```

First time method run: [textFont is ok, but textFont2 (it's font has been installed before) is broken!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvVnH.jpg)
Run the method for the second time: [textFont2 is still broken, but where is the textFont?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zTZ5.jpg)

I also use `AddFontResourceW`, returns 1 and system holds font file, but TextBlock's font is still default font:

```
AddFontResourceW(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "themes\\tmp\\text\\text.ttf");
SendMessageW(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0);
```

it's a WPF program, so `PrivateFontCollection` does not work. What other ways are there to set the font from a font file?

**Update:** I found that

```
textFont = new FontFamily("file:///" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/themes/tmp/text/#" + textFontName);
```

and this

```
textFont = new FontFamily(new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/themes/tmp/text/text.ttf", UriKind.Absolute), "./#" + textFontName);
```

Works, but until font not replaced. if i replace text.ttf to other fonts (or replace it with itself) font goes broken ([this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zTZ5.jpg))

Comment: have you tried loading them as an embedded resource or resource?

Comment: Yes, it works. But now i have archive files (something theme structure) with font files inside; i must extract them to a folder and then, set fonts from files...